# Swift, How to call a function that's in an extension in my GameScene?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm making a 2D platformer game on Swift, and I want the screen to shake when the player gets hit with a weapon. I've tried a few different solutions, like making just the background sprite shake, but it just doesn't have the same effect. I found code online that creates a shake function that I believe will shake the screen, but the only problem is I don't know how to call it in my GameScene because it's defined outside of my class. For example, this is what my code looks like:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
   // code

func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
   // call shake function
}
}

extension UIView {
func shake() {
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.linear)
    animation.duration = 0.6
    animation.values = [-20, 20, -20, 20, -10, 10, -5, 5, 0]
    self.layer.add(animation, forKey: "shake")
  }
}
```

I want to call the shake function where it says "call shake function" in my code. How would I call it?

Comment: I don't know much about SpriteKit, but all UIView instances should now have a new function called 'shake()'. But I don't think SKScene is a subclass of UIView, so that won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `shake` method is declared in an extension of `UIView`, meaning that it can be called on any `UIView` instance.

`SKView` is a kind of `UIView` that holds a `SKScene`. `SKScene`s have a `view` property that you can use to access the `SKView`. Therefore, you can call `shake` in your scene like this:

```
self.view?.shake()
```